# Excel (2013, 32-bit) Pivot table for medium-size datasets

Tags: pivot-table, excel-2013

I have a table with 48 column X 30000 rows. I'd like to have multiple tables with top 20 keys based on some filter values and then show display their records in their entirety.

Example: Show top 20 games sold in 2015 along with their titles, companies, units sold, etc. Filterable by the country of origin, platform, publish year, etc

I tried using the vanilla pivot table provided by Excel 2013 but I quickly ran into a memory issue (!). So I decided to give Power Query a try but that also seems to be a dead-end due to memory issue

Comment: 48 columns is a lot. Do you need them all? Can you drop some columns out of your source data? Is the source data a database or Excel Range? Is this a crosstab? i.e. do you have columns for 2011, 2012, ... , 2015 running across the top in the raw source data? If so, you need to do something called 'Normalization' aka 'UnPivot' so that instead of years running across the top, you have a dedicated 'Years' column. But you're going to run into a problem here because this 'stretches' the data downwards and you'll run out of rows. There's ways around this, but first let's establish if its an issue.

Comment: Not all columns are intended to be used in the pivot table. Only 10 of them are, although the needed columns are not contiguous which causes issues as well. My issue though is that even adding 1 column causes a memory issue because each column has 20-30K rows

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is my bad.

I misused the Pivot table. The column list there actually produces 1 column per combination of values in the column list. What I wanted is to instead add the column as another key column.

I will close this out.